# some of my homepage on Wordpress is blank but the links work

Tags: wordpress

blank space under header image
[www.thesportcornerbkk.com](https://thesportcornerbkk.com/wp/)
But if you click the blank space, the link still works.
I’ve never used Wordpress and I’m trying to help a friend out.
Where are the images gone?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is css issue, please open your style.css (wp/wp-content/themes/bbq/style.css) and edit the `.infobox ul > li, #pre-footer-widgets .widget-section, .gallery-container ul li` change the opacity to 1

Comment: Have you been able to try this yourself and it worked? Reason I ask is because I don’t have access to the website at the moment and I will forward your answer for him to do himself. Thank you for the quick reply

Comment: Yes, with inspect element.

Comment: style.css file row #1391 change opacity to 1 as what Ramya instructed

.infobox ul > li,
#pre-footer-widgets .widget-section,
.gallery-container ul li {
 opacity: 1,
}

Comment: All good my end, using developer tools 